# How to get the value from Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Currently im doing on a project on ordering system. Let me explain the flow of the system. In ordering class, i have 2 jtable. One of the jtables shows the list of food retrieve from the database. I just have to click on one of the food and press"add", the selected food will transfer to another jtable . After i press"proceed" i will be led to a jtable, to the next jpanel,  which consists of the food i have selected. However" i allow one cell to be editable,"quantity" is there any way on how to retrieve the data input by the user and store to database?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the implementation of the `TableModel`, you could get the data for an individual row. This would, generally, be the preferred solution, as the data for the row would be encapsulated within a POJO which maintains all the data that you need in a single place that easily manageable.

If you've just dumped a bunch of unassociated properties into the table, you will need to use something like `JTable#getValueAt` or `TableModel#getValueAt`

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details